# this error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with

Tags: node.js, express, join, registration, joi

I am getting an error while i try to create an user.  `userValidation is not a function at exports.createUser` this is a function in the validation.js file which it takes a parameter data `body-VALUES` and then to validate each input of the body. but i don't know why i am getting this error.

here is the callback function for the post request /create-user

`The requiring modules`

```
    const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const bycrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const bodyparser = require("body-parser"); //requiring the body parser     

const passport = require('passport');

const flash = require('express-session');

//import the validation file 

const userValidation = require('./validation');

exports.createUser = async(req, res, next) => {

console.log('Post CREATE User /create-user');

//validation the user 
const { error } = userValidation(req.body);

//if the req.body didn't pass the vaildation part 
if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}
```

//one of the solutions

```
  try {
    //checking if the user is already exist 

    const userExist = await userSchema.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

    if (userExist) return res.status(400).send('UserName Already Exist');
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

// the main code
//checking if the user is already exist

```
   // const userExist = await userSchema.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

  //  if (userExist) return res.status(400).send('UserName Already Exist');

//Hashing The Password


const salt = await bycrypt.genSalt(10);

const hashedPassword = await bycrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);


// creating a new user from the schema 

const user = new userSchema({
    username: req.body.username,

    password: req.body.hashedPassword
})

// saving the user inside the db

user
    .save()
    .then(data => {
        res.redirect('/halalMunchies/all-employees');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occured while creating a create operation"
        });
    });
```

};

the validation file which it exist at the same folder with the call back function, this to validate user's input

```
 //validation

const joi = require('@hapi/joi');

//creating user Schema validation 

const userValidation = (data) => {

    const schema = {

        username: joi.string().min(6).required(),

        password: joi.string().min(6).required()

    };

    return joi.validate(data, schema);

};

//creating login Schema validation 

const loginValidation = (data) => {

    const schema = {

        username: joi.string().min(6).required(),

        password: joi.string().min(6).required()

    };

    return joi.validate(data, schema);

};

//export

module.exports.userValidation = userValidation;
module.exports.loginValidation = loginValidation;
```

the Error:

```
    (node:28160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: userValidation is not a function
    at exports.createUser (E:\HalalMunchies\server\controller\usersController.js:32:23)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting ck, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejecttps://nodejs.org/aptions=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28160) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with ade.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

`THE NEXT ERROR`

```
 (node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
    at userValidation (E:\HalalMunchies\server\controller\validation.js:11:23)
    at exports.createUser (E:\HalalMunchies\server\controller\usersController.js:32:23)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5720) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js 
process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: In your first code block, you don't show where you expect the `userValidation()` function to come from.  Are you importing it from somewhere?  If so, show us that code.  If not, then that's what you need to do.

Comment: It also appears that you aren't catching exceptions/rejections either so you are vulnerable to this "unhandled rejection" if one of your other `await` statements finds a rejected promise.

Comment: Why in the world do people doublespace code?  I've never understood that.  It makes it so much harder to read as you can't see very much in one screen glance.  Hard to follow the code flow IMO - even worse in the stackoverflow scrolling code blocks.

Comment: yes i am importing the validation file inside the call back function where both of them exists in the same folder

Comment: that's a good point for the exceptions, i don't know if i have to do that but if possible can u show me an example

Comment: What, you don't know how to catch promise rejections?  Either use `.catch()` on a promise or `try/catch` around an `await`.

Comment: i did that just now and i got the same error, i will edit my updates on that rn.

Comment: Yeah, of course.  Catching the error doesn't make the error go away, it just gives you a change to "handle" it.  See my answer below for a way to fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
const userValidation = require('./validation');
```

is not correct.  According to your validation file, it would need to be this:

```
const userValidation = require('./validation').userValidation;
```

or this:

```
const { userValidation } = require('./validation');
```

Comment: thanks for this another i guess it passes this error but i got another error, i will update the question rn. I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP BRO.

Comment: @HeshamEldawy - Now, it looks like you aren't importing `joi` properly

Comment: how ?? and also here i created the question description here so it can be helpful for everyone https://stackoverflow.com/q/69960084/15454800